# How to recalculate the height of the ion-row

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm developing an App where a certain time is generated a list, see:

[image]

The CSS **layer** class fills up the part next to the ion-footer, but when the list grows too much the class does not work properly, see:

[image]

How can I fix this? It follows CSS class, but I think the problem is not in it, but in something of Ionic itself.

**ION-CONTENT**

```
<ion-content class="background">
    <ion-grid class="layer">
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-12>
                <div class="title">
                    <p>
                        <strong>Listas de exercícios ({{amountList}})</strong>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
                <ion-list>
                    <button ion-item *ngFor="let exercise of exercises" (click)="itemSelected(exercise.id)">
                    {{ exercise.name }}
                  </button>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

**CSS**

```
.background {
    background: url(../assets/imgs/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.layer {
    background-color: rgba(104, 101, 101, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use an ion-scroll for your ion-list